# Ho to replicate illustrator's text highlight?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, transparency, blend-modes

I'm really new to designing, and im trying to replicate illustrator's text highlight, to my original image.
Here is the effect that im trying to replicate: 
[image: effect]
We can see that the 'you' is highlighted, i did this, just by selecting the text in illustrator.

I know you can't highlight text in illustrator, but we can use a rectangle instead.
Here is what i tried:

1. Make a rectangle the same size as the one in the picture and place one layer below the text.
2. Change rectangle color to 'E3DFDF'
3. Change opacity to 80%

This is what i got:
[image: what i tried]

I couldn't replicate the same effect, and would like some info on how to produce the same effect.

I'm using illustrator CC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a white box over the top and change the Opacity Mode in the Transparency palette to Difference. The document colour mode needs to be RGB.

[image]